# How to detect user has completed embedded Typeform?

Tags: javascript, forms, typeform

I have a [Typeform](https://www.typeform.com/) embedded into my page inside an iframe. From my JS I would like to know that user has finished the typeform (i.e. clicked Submit). The typeform JS does not seem to provide any events one can listen to. Currently I figured out only following solution -- to call periodically following test to detect that the outro page is being displayed:

```
document.getElementById('my-typeform-iframe').getElementsByClassName('outro').length > 0
```

Is there some nicer approach?

Answer (score 11):

ok, so it I was wrong in my assumptions above - it turns out the typeform iframe emits an event when user submits the form. the event is named `form-submit` and one can process it e.g. this way:

```
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
      if(event.data == 'form-submit')
        // your business logic here
    }, false);
```

Comment: does not seem to work anymore... `event.data` is always the same id now

Comment: Have to use event.data.type === "form-submit" now

Comment: The 'form-submit' string belongs to the `event.data.type`.

Answer (score 9):

Typeform now has a 'onSubmit' callback feature for that.

```
<script src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("my-embedded-typeform");
    window.typeformEmbed.makeWidget(el, "https://admin.typeform.com/to/cVa5IG", {
    onSubmit: function() {
      alert("submited!");
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/callbacks/)

Apparently there's no easy way to **retrieve the answers**. As mentioned by @matthew, a response_id is passed to the callback (I guess), and you can query the API with that but you need to implement a retry loop because responses are not immediately available.

Comment: How do you get the values of the form?

Comment: I don't think you can get it right away in the callback. Here's what I do:
1. onSubmit send an xhr to the server
2. The server recognize the user that submitted the form (by cookie or request param)
3. The server do an API call to typeform with a search query containing the id or the email of the user to get his response.
4. I process the response data on the server only

You could send it back to the client if you need

Comment: My experience for those who follow @apflieger's suggestion is the response is not immediately available after submission via Typeform's API (just confirmed with Typeform that this is known behavior). The onSubmit callback receives the response_id but immediately querying Typeform with that response_id will return an error for up to 20 seconds or so (that's been my experience)...

Comment: Yeah, I loop some retries to retrieve the response. But I didn't know there's a response id returned somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to peter answer, I checked the event they provided and get few good results. here is my findings:

```
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
  if(event.data.type == 'form-submit')
    // your business logic here
}, false);
```

The event data have a couple of types which is:

- form-theme
- TARP
- form-ready
- form-height-changed
- form-screen-changed
- A JSON event with no type that have the form answers
- A JSON event with the form submit information
- form-submit
- embed-auto-close-popup